# AES authentication on passwordless SSH in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, encryption, ssh, aes

I had enabled passwordless ssh on some servers and wrote a perl file to execute some commands from one server to another server

```
@KEYFILE = ("/path/.ssh/id_dsa");
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host,
                debug=>1, identity_files=>\@KEYFILE,
                protocol=>'2,1');
```

this lines to create a new connection is working for some servers but one of the server is asking for AES authentication, so in my perl script i changed the above line to the below line

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host,
              options => [ "Ciphers aes256-ctr" ]);
```

but now it is showing permission denied.

So can anybody help me on this to run passwordless ssh with AES authentication.
I am working on a Linux machine.

Comment: Can you manually ssh in?  If not, try ssh -vvv to see what the problem might be.

Comment: I tried ssh -v the output that I got is
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: AES authentication required
root@alloy4's password:

Comment: Probably Net::SSH::Perl just doesn't support AES. That module has been mostly unmaintained for a long time. Try using Net::OpenSSH instead.